# Implementing Classic OPC DA Server from scratch

Tags: c++, c, opc

I would like to implement my own OPC DA Server (versions 1. X-2. X) from scratch but without using any third-party. I have a  classical OPC DA client (COM/DCOM based). So I need to create an opc DA Server which can connect to the server.

Is there any kind of document that explains detailed and step by step the process to implement an OPC client?

Comment: "an opc DA Server which can connect to the server" ?

Answer (score 1):

To implement from scratch an OPC DA Server I recommend you to read the OPC DA Specification.
But why do you want to implement an OPC DA Server 1.x or 2.x since the last (2003) is 3 ?

On the OPC Foundation you could find the specification for [OPC DA 2.05](http://www.opcfoundation.org/DownloadFile.aspx?CM=3&RI=66&CN=KEY&CI=274&CU=21) or [OPC DA 3](http://www.opcfoundation.org/DownloadFile.aspx?CM=3&RI=67&CN=KEY&CI=274&CU=21).
However you need to be a member of the OPC Foundation to download them !

I think it may be a best alternative for you to consider OPC UA. This is a much more interesting solution since OPC DA will be soon deprecated !

Answer (score 0):

While I don't agree that OPC DA will disappear any time soon I think it would be better if you focus on doing a OPC UA server. There are (or at least there will be) adapters that allow you to connect a OPC DA client to an OPC UA server.

There is an open source OPC UA project that you can look at where you can get the source code from, that should be a good start.

See http://www.openopcua.org/

Comment: With the development of more and more OPC Gateways DA/UA, people will start to think about implementing OPC UA. I think the security issues will be a also a key fact in jumping into UA. But ok, soon was not maybe the right word ;)